# How do I decide which way to backtrack in the Smith–Waterman algorithm?

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics

I am trying to implement local sequence alignment in Python using the [Smith–Waterman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

Here's what I have so far. It gets as far as building the [similarity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_matrix):

```
import sys, string
from numpy import *

f1=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
seq1=f1.readline()
f1.close()
seq1=string.strip(seq1)

f2=open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
seq2=f2.readline()
f2.close()
seq2=string.strip(seq2)

a,b =len(seq1),len(seq2)

penalty=-1;
point=2;

#generation of matrix for local alignment
p=zeros((a+1,b+1))

# table calculation and matrix generation
for i in range(1,a+1):
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        vertical_score =p[i-1][j]+penalty;
        horizontal_score= p[i][j-1]+penalty;
        if seq1[i-1]==seq2[j-1]:
            diagonal_score =p[i-1][j-1]+point;
        else:
            diagonal_score = p[i-1][j-1]+penalty;
        p[i][j]=max(0,vertical_score,horizontal_score,diagonal_score);

print p
```

For example, with the two sequences:

```
agcacact
acacacta
```

my code outputs the similarity matrix:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   2.   1.   2.   1.   2.   1.   0.   2.]
 [  0.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   0.   1.]
 [  0.   0.   3.   2.   3.   2.   3.   2.   1.]
 [  0.   2.   2.   5.   4.   5.   4.   3.   4.]
 [  0.   1.   4.   4.   7.   6.   7.   6.   5.]
 [  0.   2.   3.   6.   6.   9.   8.   7.   8.]
 [  0.   1.   4.   5.   8.   8.  11.  10.   9.]
 [  0.   0.   3.   4.   7.   7.  10.  13.  12.]]
```

Now I am stuck on the next step of the algorithm, the backtracking to construct the best alignment.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm#Example),

> To obtain the optimum local alignment, we start with the highest value in the matrix (*i*, *j*). Then, we go backwards to one of positions (*i* − 1, *j*), (*i*, *j* − 1), and (*i* − 1, *j* − 1) depending on the direction of movement used to construct the matrix. We keep the process until we reach a matrix cell with zero value, or the value in position (0, 0).

I am having trouble determining which position to backtrack to. What does Wikipedia mean by "depending on the direction of movement used to construct the matrix" mean and how would I implement this in Python?

Finally I did this

```
import sys, string
from numpy import*
import re

# read first sequence

fasta_sequence1=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

seq1=""
for i in fasta_sequence1:
    if i.startswith(">"):
        pass
    else:
        seq1 = seq1 + i.strip()   
fasta_sequence1.close()

fasta_sequence2=open(sys.argv[2], 'r')

seq2 = ""
for i in fasta_sequence2:
    if i.startswith('>'):
        pass
    else:
        seq2 = seq2+ i.strip()
fasta_sequence2.close()

a,b =len(seq1),len(seq2)


penalty=-1;
point=2;

#generation of matrix for local alignment 

p=zeros((a+1,b+1))

#intialization of max score
max_score=0;
#pointer to store the traceback path

pointer=zeros((a+1,b+1))

# table calculation and matrix generation
for i in range(1,a+1):
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        vertical_score =p[i-1][j]+penalty;
        horizontal_score= p[i][j-1]+penalty;
        if seq1[i-1]==seq2[j-1]:
            diagonal_score =p[i-1][j-1]+point;
        else:
            diagonal_score = p[i-1][j-1]+penalty;

for i in range(1,a+1):
    for j in range(1,b+1):            
        p[i][j]=max(0,vertical_score,horizontal_score,diagonal_score);

for i in range(1,a+1):
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        if p[i][j]==0:
            pointer[i][j]=0; #0 means end of the path
        if p[i][j]==vertical_score:
            pointer[i][j]=1; #1 means trace up
        if p[i][j]==horizontal_score:
            pointer[i][j]=2; #2 means trace left
        if p[i][j]==diagonal_score:
            pointer[i][j]=3; #3 means trace diagonal
        if p[i][j]>=max_score:
            maximum_i=i;
            maximum_j=j;
            max_score=p[i][j];


#for i in range(1,a+1):
   # for j in range(1,b+1):
        #if p[i][j]>max_score:
            #max_score=p[i][j]

print max_score

# traceback of all the pointers 

align1,align2='',''; #initial sequences

i,j=max_i,max_j; #indices of path starting point

while pointer[i][j]!=0:
  if pointer[i][j]==3:
    align1=align1+seq1[i-1];
    align2=align2+seq2[j-1];
    i=i-1;
    j=j-1;
  elif pointer[i][j]==2:
    align1=align1+'-';
    align2=align2+seq2[j-1]
    j=j-1;
  elif pointer[i][j]==1:
    align1=align1+seq1[i-1];
    align2=align2+'-';
    i=i-1;



align1=align1[::-1]; #reverse sequence 1
align2=align2[::-1]; #reverse sequence 2

#output_file = open(sys.argv[3],"w")
#output_file.write(align1)

#output_file.write(align2)

print align1
print align2
```

But i think there could be a better and more efficient way of doing this

```
output_file = open(sys.argv[3],"w")
output_file.write(align1)
output_file.write(align2)
```

the result shows like

```
agcacacta-cacact
```

on the contraryc for :

```
print align1
print align2
```

shows correct output:

```
agcacact
a-cacact
```

How can i get the above output in the file writer . Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you build the similarity matrix, you need to store not only the similarity score, but *where that score came from*. You currently have a line of code:

```
p[i][j]=max(0,vertical_score,horizontal_score,diagonal_score);
```

so here you need to remember not the just the maximum score, but *which of these* was the maximum. Then when you come to do the backtracking you will know which direction to go.

For example, you might try something like this:

```
import numpy

DELETION, INSERTION, MATCH = range(3)

def smith_waterman(seq1, seq2, insertion_penalty = -1, deletion_penalty = -1,
                   mismatch_penalty = -1, match_score = 2):
    """
    Find the optimum local sequence alignment for the sequences `seq1`
    and `seq2` using the Smith-Waterman algorithm. Optional keyword
    arguments give the gap-scoring scheme:

    `insertion_penalty` penalty for an insertion (default: -1)
    `deletion_penalty`  penalty for a deletion (default: -1)
    `mismatch_penalty`  penalty for a mismatch (default: -1)
    `match_score`       score for a match (default: 2)

    See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm>.

    >>> for s in smith_waterman('AGCAGACT', 'ACACACTA'): print s
    ... 
    AGCAGACT-
    A-CACACTA
    """
    m, n = len(seq1), len(seq2)

    # Construct the similarity matrix in p[i][j], and remember how
    # we constructed it -- insertion, deletion or (mis)match -- in
    # q[i][j].
    p = numpy.zeros((m + 1, n + 1))
    q = numpy.zeros((m + 1, n + 1))
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            deletion = (p[i - 1][j] + deletion_penalty, DELETION)
            insertion = (p[i][j - 1] + insertion_penalty, INSERTION)
            if seq1[i - 1] == seq2[j - 1]:
                match = (p[i - 1][j - 1] + match_score, MATCH)
            else:
                match = (p[i - 1][j - 1] + mismatch_penalty, MATCH)
            p[i][j], q[i][j] = max((0, 0), deletion, insertion, match)

    # Yield the aligned sequences one character at a time in reverse
    # order.
    def backtrack():
        i, j = m, n
        while i > 0 or j > 0:
            assert i >= 0 and j >= 0
            if q[i][j] == MATCH:
                i -= 1
                j -= 1
                yield seq1[i], seq2[j]
            elif q[i][j] == INSERTION:
                j -= 1
                yield '-', seq2[j]
            elif q[i][j] == DELETION:
                i -= 1
                yield seq1[i], '-'
            else:
                assert(False)

    return [''.join(reversed(s)) for s in zip(*backtrack())]
```

Comment: how cani print the output in a file with with the strings one above the other .

Comment: Write a newline character to the file after the first string and before the second string.

Comment: As it is on a mismatch the 2 aligned strings may include different letters on the same position (when `MATCH` stems from a mismatch in constructing p) - correct ? Also `while p[i][j] != 0` might as well be `while q[i][j] != 0`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Yes, a mismatch means that the two strings have different letters at the same position. I added a mismatch to the doctest example to illustrate this. Also, you're right to query the backtracking loop condition: it was wrong, and I've now fixed it.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong - deleted. What I meant to say however was that SW is a "local" alignment algorithm which means that : A) backtrack does not necessarily start at (m,n) and B) there must be a fourth value (typically 0 - hence my confusion) to signal that backtracking must stop. So one must keep the highest score (and its position) and start backtracking from it `while q[i][j] != STOP`. Still +1 for succinctness.